# Give me possible reasons why I can't connect with SQL Pro in Berlin?

Tags: sql

My knowledge is not very deep on this.

Since I have been in Germany I have not been able to connect to any of my sites via SQL Pro.  I can go through PHPmyAdmin ... But its a pain!

Here is the message I'm getting:

MySQL said: Access denied for user 'wwwberli'@'port-92-195-251-253.dynamic.qsc.de' (using password: YES)

This happens everywhere in Berlin (apartments / cafes / workspace) .. is there something I am just not aware of here?  Something to do with dynamic IP?

Does anyone have any possible ideas?  I don't have a "personal" ISP here so I can't really contact them (staying at short-term apartment)... But are there are some steps I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Probably MySQL only allows connections from localhost and your home IP address so this is why it is working from PHPmyAdmin which runs on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Server firewall settings. It can also be due to your dynamic IP.